# Ctrl+C in terminal producing python traceback, on trying an invalid command

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, terminal

I entered an invalid command, `d` into my linux terminal. It usually takes around 1 second before it would print `d: command not found`. Today, I hit `Ctrl+C` before it could print 'command not found', and got the following output:

```
user@mypc:~/$ d
^C
user@mypc:~/$ Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 586, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 573, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 358, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 212, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 164, in addpackage
    f = open(fullname, "r")
KeyboardInterrupt

user@mypc:~/$
```

Why did this happen?

Edit: here is the output of the which command:

```
$ which xyx
$
$ which d
$
```

Comment: What does `which d` print out?

Comment: It doesn't print anything. I don't think this behavior is special of `d`

Comment: @Pratyaksh; WHICH should either print the path of the file, or state "no xxx in ...". Show us screen output where he returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot - Can you do : which -v

Comment: It shows `Illegal option -v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu includes a ["command not found" handler](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found) in their Bash setup, which is written in Python. I guess you interrupted that.

One second sounds like a long time. Is your system very old, or under heavy load?

Comment: Yes it is both old and under somewhat heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that when you hit the keyboard interrupt key, python did not not reach that part of your program that subsitute "d" into **a particular set of codes** that would usually generate this error. So you didn't have the error "`d: command not found`" and also another part of your codes that also takes 'd' before it reaches the codes that gives `d: command not found` is now giving an error since 'd' is not a number.

However, based on the info...It simply appears that your program was interrupted  when python was invoking one of its module and as a result you have an error message since this process wasn't completed.

Comment: I edited my answer with a little explanation how what I think when you hit Ctrl+C suddenly. Hope this helps